# Editing Point Data Layer made from Database Table using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, sql-server

I have a project in ArcGIS Pro which is connected to a SQL Server Database. I made a point feature layer from one of the tables however I cannot add points to the layer. I connected to the database using the account which I created the database in, so I am the database owner, and the tables are loading correctly however when I make a feature layer using the tables, I cannot edit the layer.

EDIT: By a point feature layer, I added the table that contained the fields I would wish to be able to populate in my database to the map. From there I highlighted the map layer, selected "Add Data" and chose "XY Point Data" from the drop down menu (this is in the "Layer" group from the Map menu in the ribbon).

This newly created layer I imported into my database sde, however if I want to add points to this layer, I cannot. I get the message:

> This enterprise database table is not registered with the Geodatabase. Edits cannot be made.

The problem is I cannot "register" the table because the option is greyed out under the "Manage" option when I right-click the database table. I also noticed that the "Priveleges" winddow indicates to me that I am not the data owner, eventhough I'm using the same account in the Data Source as I did when I made the database, an account that is also the database administrator. I also named the schema the same as the admin user because I read that that can be a problem.

How do I configure the database so that it recognizes my user as the data owner?

Comment: I've elaborated a little more on the steps I've taken. Kindly see editted question.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  So it looks like you've created an X/Y Event Layer and then exported this as a feature class to your database.  You say the database is an SDE.  So how did you export the data to the SDE (enterprise geodatabase)?

Comment: Yes, I right clicked the sde and imported the feature layer from the Default.gdb

Answer (score 1):

OK so I realized that I can't make edits to a database created outside of ArcGIS, I needed to Create a geodatabase through ArcGIS, I'm a n00b.

[Here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/overview-geodatabases-sqlserver.htm) is where I found my answer.